# Dolphin browser doesn't opens link to local pdf on android

Tags: android, html, pdf, browser, href

I have android tab, folder with two files:
-index.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="test.pdf">LINK</a>
</body>
</html>
```

-file test pdf

On PC, i clicked on LINK and test.pdf opens. On android default browser, i clicked on LINK and test.pdf opens on kingsoft office. But on android dolphin browser i clicked on LINK but test.pdf will not opens, opens only kingsoft office. I have the feeling, that the dolphin browser loses a link (or thinks it is wrong link) on the file and opens only the office. Anybody can help me?

If i try open LINK on new tab in dolphin browser, i get following error:
The url is not supported for download!

Comment: even technical support did not answer.

Comment: instead of a relative path, `<a href="/test.pdf";>LINK</a>`, have you tried an absolute path? For example, `<a href="http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/test.pdf";>LINK</a>`